# How to search by country in Search.class.php?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry i'm new to PHP/MySQL. In the code below how do I search by country? I have tried changing the code but I get errors.

Thanks

```
echo $this->country; //what I want to search by

    if($bsiCore->config['conf_rental_type'] == 1){

        $searchsql_count = mysql_query("select count(*) from bsi_apartment_master as bam, bsi_appmt_features as baf where  bam.status=true and  baf.appmt_id=bam.appmt_id".$addquery." and baf.bedroom >=".$this->bedroom." and baf.bathroom >=".$this->bathroom." and bam.appmt_id not in (select appmt_id from bsi_bookings WHERE is_deleted = FALSE AND (('".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' BETWEEN checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) OR (DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) OR (checkin_date BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) OR (DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY))))   ");

        $searchsql = "SELECT pp_id, appmt_id, price, max( stay_from )
                        FROM (
                        SELECT bp.pp_id, bam.appmt_id, bam.appmt_name, bp.price, bp.stay_from
                        FROM bsi_apartment_master AS bam, bsi_appmt_features AS baf, bsi_priceplan AS bp
                        WHERE bam.status=true and baf.appmt_id = bam.appmt_id".$addquery." AND baf.bedroom >=".$this->bedroom." AND baf.bathroom >=".$this->bathroom." 
                        AND bam.appmt_id NOT IN (SELECT appmt_id FROM bsi_bookings WHERE is_deleted = FALSE AND (( '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."'
                        BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                        OR ( DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                        OR ( checkin_date BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                        OR ( checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) )))
                        AND bam.appmt_id = bp.appmt_id
                        AND if( ( ".$staycount." NOT BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) = true, 
                        ( ".$staycount." NOT BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) AND bp.default_pp !=0, 
                        ( ".$staycount." BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) )
                        order by bp.stay_from desc
                        ) AS t1
                        GROUP BY appmt_id
                        order by price ".$this->sorting;
```

Comment: Is country a field in one of your database tables? If so which one? And what is the name of your country field?

Comment: @Jrod - it is a field in the database. The echo in the code above displays the country selected previously. There is a function with the details:  public function getCountrycombo($country=""){
  $html = '<option value="">-- All Country --</option>';
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT `country` FROM `bsi_apartment_master` WHERE status=true group by country order by country");

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. On the index page I had the following drop down box:

```
<select id="country_select" name="country_select" class="home-select">
<?php echo $bsiCore->getCountrycombo();?>
</select>
```

In Search.class.php I just added the following in the mysql search criteria:

```
and bam.country='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['country_select']))."'
```